RabbitMQ: multiple consumers read from single queue with custom workload splitting
Is it possible to configure on RabbitMQ queue that depending on for example routing key it will be send to specified consumer?
It means that to same queue can be send events with routing keys like

project-created-0
project-created-1
project-created-2
project-created-...

Event with routing key project-created-0 will be send to consumer 1, with routing key project-created-1 to consumer 2 etc

Queues in RabbitMQ to store messages and feed them to consumers on that queue.
The routing in RabbitMQ is done by the exchange and binding to those queues.
So, you might need to revise your logic. The queue for specific routing key is for specific consumer. The exchange will decide to which queue to route that message.
What is good with AMQP protocol that consumer by itself may create and bind queue into particular exchange.
See more info in documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java
